# MATLAB decoding ''braille'' using a table file to decode input into english. Issue with string being returned as a double

Tags: matlab, for-loop, decoding, braille

MATLAB decoding ''braille'' using a table file to decode input into english. Issue with string being returned as a double + possible incorrect use of iterations in for loop?

for instance an input of a matrix = [1 0 0; 0 0 0] (which is equivalent to the first six elements in the table file) will return a double = [97, 0]
also, I'm not sure where the zero is coming from
I'm lost and would appreciate any hints. Thank you :)

```
function output = b_decode(input);
load('braille_table.mat', 'table');

x = numel(input)
[r,c] = size(input)
str = zeros(1,c)
for i = 1:6:c;
j = 1:1:(c./2);

if input(i:i+5) == table(1:6)
      str(j) = 'a'

  elseif input(i:i+5) == table(7:12)
      str(j) = 'b'

  elseif input(i:i+5) == table(13:18)
      str(j) = 'c'

  elseif input(i:i+5) == table(19:24)
      str(j) = 'd'

  elseif input(i:i+5) == table(25:30)
      str(j) = 'e'

  elseif input(i:i+5) == table(31:36)
      str(j) = 'f'

  elseif input(i:i+5) == table(37:42)
      str(j) = 'g'

  elseif input(i:i+5) == table(43:48)
      str(j) = 'h'

  elseif input(i:i+5) == table(49:54)
      str(j) = 'i'

  elseif input(i:i+5) == table(55:60)
      str(j) = 'j'

  elseif input(i:i+5) == table(61:66)
      str(j) = 'k'

  elseif input(i:i+5) == table(67:72)
        str(j) = 'l';

  elseif input(i:i+5) == table(73:78)
      str(j) = 'm'

  elseif input(i:i+5) == table(79:84)
      str(j) = 'n'

  elseif input(i:i+5) == table(85:90)
      str(j) = 'o'

  elseif input(i:i+5) == table(91:96)
      str(j) = 'p';

  elseif input(i:i+5) == table(97:102)
      str(j) = 'q'

  elseif input(i:i+5) == table(103:108)
      str(j) = 'r';

  elseif input(i:i+5) == table(109:114)
      str(j) = 's'

  elseif input(i:i+5) == table(115:120)
      str(j) = 't'

  elseif input(i:i+5) == table(121:126)
      str(j) = 'u'

  elseif input(i:i+5) == table(127:132)
      str(j) = 'v'

  elseif input(i:i+5) == table(133:138)
      str(j) = 'w'

  elseif input(i:i+5) == table(139:144)
      str(j) = 'x'

  elseif input(i:i+5) == table(145:150)
      str(j) = 'y'

  elseif  input(i:i+5) == table(151:156)
                str(j) == 'z'


end


end;
    output = str

    end
```

Answer (score 1):

`zeros` initializes a double array, use `blanks` to initialize an empty char array:

```
str = blanks(c)
```